# How to Export Dump in Oracle 11g and Import in Oracle 9i

Tags: oracle, oracle11g

Can any one please help me for solving this Issue. I need to Export a dump in Oracle 11g and Import in Oracle 9i. I sucessfully Exported in Oracle 11g , But Upon Importing in Oracle 9i, its showing error. Please provide me solution for this. THANKS IN ADVANCE

Comment: This questions lacks a lot of necessary information - please edit your question and add the export command/script, import command/script plus the error message you got.

Comment: IMP SYSTEM/SYSTEMPASS FILE=D:\test.DMP SHOW=N IGNORE=N GRANTS=Y FROMUSER=user1 TOUSER=user2 ROWS=Y

Answer (score 1):

You probably get the error because you created the export file using the 11G version of the export utility. 
Give it a try by using the Oracle 9i version of the export utility to create the export.

Comment: How to change the export utility in oracle 11g, can you advice me please.

Comment: You need a oracle 9i client.

Comment: AM having oralce 9i client, how to configure that

Comment: Make sure you use the exp.exe from the oracle 9i client when you make the export.